# Trim end off of string in swift, getting error at runtime

Tags: ios, string, swift, substring, trim

I'm making a calculator app in Swift, once my answer is obtained I want to display it in a UILabel. Only problem is I want to limit said answer to 8 characters. Here is my code:

```
let answerString = "\(answer)"
    println(answer)
    calculatorDisplay.text = answerString.substringToIndex(advance(answerString.startIndex, 8))
```

This does not return any compiler errors but at runtime I get:

```
fatal error: can not increment endIndex
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think  answerString.startIndex, 8) function returning the value greater hte answerstring

Comment: That is a possibility, and something that could happen in the app. Will try a workaround and get back to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two different `advance()` functions:

```
/// Return the result of advancing `start` by `n` positions. ...
func advance<T : ForwardIndexType>(start: T, n: T.Distance) -> T

/// Return the result of advancing start by `n` positions, or until it
/// equals `end`. ...
func advance<T : ForwardIndexType>(start: T, n: T.Distance, end: T) -> T
```

Using the second one you can ensure that the result is within the valid bounds of the string:

```
let truncatedText = answerString.substringToIndex(advance(answerString.startIndex, 8, answerString.endIndex))
```

Update for **Swift 2/Xcode 7:**

```
let truncatedText = answerString.substringToIndex(answerString.startIndex.advancedBy(8, limit: answerString.endIndex))
```

But a simpler solution is

```
let truncatedText = String(answerString.characters.prefix(8))
```

Update for **Swift 3/Xcode 8 beta 6:** As of Swift 3, "collections move
their index", the corresponding code is now

```
let to = answerString.index(answerString.startIndex,
                            offsetBy: 8,
                            limitedBy: answerString.endIndex)
let truncatedText = answerString.substring(to: to ?? answerString.endIndex)
```

The simpler solution

```
let truncatedText = String(answerString.characters.prefix(8))
```

still works.